# JavaScripts not recognizing var holding parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, css, json, ajax, justgage

I'm trying to code some gauges for an index page for various R/Shiny dashboards our company uses. The page is just a series of divs with some styling on them that lead to those various R apps.

Recently our execs expressed a lot of interest in seeing fuel-gauge style graphs on the top of the page signifying $income and $goals for the month for each division.

I decided to use the [JustGage](http://justGage.com) plugin to make the Gauges. We're getting the data out of csv's using a script my supervisor is throwing together to dump that data into JSON docs on the server. We're talking a JSON file with 6 lines. Very simple.

I'm using an AJAX XMLHttpRequest, and that seems to have worked. However, whenI go to store the parsed data into a variable and then reference it in my Gauge parameters, I get:

> (index):182 Uncaught ReferenceError: feeData is not defined
>       at (index):182
>   (anonymous) @ (index):182

in the inspect window.

That particular line is the first reference to that var containing the JSON data.

Any help would be...well, helpful!

```js
< script >
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var feeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var feeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "test.json", true);
xhttp.send();
var g = new JustGage({
  titleFontColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black",
  id: "DEF",
  value: feeData.DEFCurrent,
  pointer: true,
  min: 0,
  max: feeData.DEFGoal,
  title: "DEF"
});
var g = new JustGage({
  titleFontColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black",
  id: "EBO",
  value: feeData.EBOCurrent,
  pointer: true,
  min: 0,
  max: feeData.EBOGoal,
  title: "EBO"
});
var g = new JustGage({
  titleFontColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black",
  id: "Company",
  value: (feeData.EBOCurrent + feeData.DEFCurrent),
  pointer: true,
  min: 0,
  max: (feeData.EBOGoal + feeData.DEFGoal),
  title: "Company"
});
var g = new JustGage({
  titleFontColor: "black",
  labelFontColor: "black",
  id: "Legal",
  value: feeData.LegalCurrent,
  pointer: true,
  min: 0,
  max: feeData.LegalGoal,
  title: "Legal"
}); 
</script>
```

Here's the JSON file

```
{"EBOGoal":1000,"EBOCurrent":900,"DEFGoal":2000,"DEFCurrent":1500,"LegalGoal":500,"LegalCurrent":450}
```

It may also be worth mentioning that the Gauges themselves work perfectly fine when I swap in dummy numeric values for the MAX and VALUE parameters of the js code for the Gauges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable declaration issue, as well as a timing issue. Even if you fix the problem by moving the variable out of the `onreadystatechange` function scope, your code will be broken because the data is populated asynchronously and the rest of your code is processed synchronously. I suggest you either move your `JustGage` initialization into a function and call that function when your `feeData` is available:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var feeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // call your function with the data
    setupJustGage(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
  }
};

function setupJustGage(feeData) {
    ...
    var g = new JustGage({
      titleFontColor: "black",
      labelFontColor: "black",
      id: "DEF",
      value: feeData.DEFCurrent,
      pointer: true,
      min: 0,
      max: feeData.DEFGoal,
      title: "DEF"
    });
    var g = new JustGage({
      titleFontColor: "black",
      labelFontColor: "black",
      id: "EBO",
      value: feeData.EBOCurrent,
      pointer: true,
      min: 0,
      max: feeData.EBOGoal,
      title: "EBO"
    });
    ...
}
```

You could also wrap your XHR request in a function that returns a `Promise` and run the rest of your setup code in the `then`:

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          var feeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "test.json", true);
        xhttp.send();
    })
}

getData().then(function(feeData) {
   var g = ...
})
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Seems so obvious in retrospect now.